# Slicing arrays based on boolean array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-logic, object-slicing

I need to slice an array of xyz coordinates based on conditions in a boolean array (where the boolean array is 1D).

If my boolean array is

> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

I need it to slice it to produce the following index arrays:

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12] ([:-2] between True indices)

The ultimate desired output would be an array of the xyz coordinates at those indices:

> [xyz[0], xyz[1], xyz[2] xyz[3], xyz[6] xyz[7], xyz[10] xyz[11], xyz[12]]

The other two slices (with similar desired outputs) are as follows:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13] ([1:-1] between True indices)
>
> [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14] ([2:] between True indices)

Is there a pythonic way to do this without a list comprehension?

Thank you!

Comment: What should be a result of this "slice", e.g. what output is expected for `[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12] ([:-2] between True indices)`?

Comment: The indices are the output (I think). The ultimate goal is to isolate the xyz coordinates of interest at those indices. I will edit the question for clarity

Comment: Why without list comprehension? This is probably the most pythonic way

Comment: I'm trying to vectorize a large portion of code, so I'm trying to avoid list comprehensions where possible and rely on mapping as much as possible. Some of the list comprehensions are unavoidable, I just wanted to know if in this case, there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [`numpy.ndarray.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nonzero.html#numpy.ndarray.nonzero) is what you need:

```
a = np.asarray([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
print(a.nonzero())
```

Outputs:

```
array([ 0,  5,  6,  9, 10, 14])
```